# What Web Hosting Service do I use for JRuby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, hosting, jruby, jrubyonrails

I'm developing a website with JRuby on Rails because I need some Java functionality server-side. I figure to deploy it, I will need to use a hosting service that supports JSP. Am I right and is that all I need? Or is there something else I will need to deploy my site? How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine with any host that supports java servlets. Then you simply run [warbler](http://kenai.com/projects/warbler/pages/Home) on your jruby on rails project and deploy the war-file. I am currently doing this with stax (http://www.stax.net) and it works fine.